# Share one variable amongst several objects

Tags: ruby

```
class Collie
    def speak
        puts dog_generic
    end
end

class Greyhound
    def speak
        puts dog_generic
    end
end

class Labrador 
    def speak
        puts dog_generic
    end
end

dog_generic = "Woof" 

chep = Collie.new
wrex = Collie.new
speedy = Greyhound.new
faithful = Labrador.new

chep.speak #=> Woof
wrex.speak #=> Woof
speedy.speak #=> Woof
faithful.speak #=> Woof
```

I'd like those last three methods to all return "Woof". However, this code will call an **undefined variable dog_generic** error. This seems to be because even global variables aren't available to objects. If I were to change all instances of `dog_generic` to `@@dog_generic`, it would work, but `@@ variables` are rarely used, and based on that alone, I can't help thinking I'd be doing it wrong.

How can I share one variable amongst several objects?

And no, I don't want to pass in a string of "Woof" to every single object as a parameter.

Comment: Were I doing this in PHP I'd create one class called `Dog`, containing my variable `dog_generic` and method `speak`, then I'd create new classes of `Collie`, `Greyhound` and `Labrador` that inherit from `Dog`. Regret I don't know how to do this in Ruby, but I hope it gives you a clue.

Comment: If you prepend all instances of `dog_generic` with a dollar sign like so `$dog_generic` you'll get the desired behaviour.  Using inheritance is a better way though, as per perimosocordiae's answer

Comment: You can just make a constant, `DOG_GENERIC = "Woof"`.

Comment: You _do not_ share one variable among several objects. Variables are private things, they _belong to_ object instances. What you do, is define a getter and setter method on the object owning the variable, and ask, or better yet, _tell_ the owner of the variable what do you want to do with the variable contents.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, one would use inheritance to provide this sort of behavior:

```
class Dog
    def speak
        puts "Woof"
    end
end

class Collie < Dog
   # whatever behavior that is specific to Collie here
end

chep = Collie.new
chep.speak #=> Woof
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :-)  Graffiker, this is one of the reasons for classes and sub-classes. You can also override the method `speak` if you want to for a particular sub class.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have some confusion about what a global variable in ruby is.  You have to explicitly make them global, with the $ sigil, a la

```
$dog_generic = 'Woof'
```

and

```
def speak
    puts $dog_generic
end
```

That said, using a global is probably your worst approach here.  Defining either a generic dog class and having your specific types inherit, or else creating a dog mixin and including it would both be better solutions IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Make a constant.  Any variable starting with a capital letter is a constant.  Including classes, so constants can be scoped globally.  `class Foo; end` is a constant that points to a class, you could also write this as `Foo = Class.new`.

```
class Collie
  def speak
    puts DOG_GENERIC
  end
end

class Greyhound
  def speak
    puts DOG_GENERIC
  end
end

class Labrador 
  def speak
    puts DOG_GENERIC
  end
end

DOG_GENERIC = "Woof" 

chep = Collie.new
wrex = Collie.new
speedy = Greyhound.new
faithful = Labrador.new

chep.speak #=> Woof
wrex.speak #=> Woof
speedy.speak #=> Woof
faithful.speak #=> Woof
```

I agree with @perimosocordiae, you should probably use inheritance.  I would disagree with him though on use of a class for inheritance.  Modules in Ruby are included in the inheritance chain, however, they do not have constructors (you can think of them as abstract classes, but you can inherit multiple modules).

```
module Speach
  WOOF = "Woof"
  QUACK = "Quack"

  module Dog
    def speak
      puts WOOF
    end
  end

  module Duck
    def speak
      puts QUACK
    end
  end
end

class Collie
  include Speach::Dog
end

class Greyhound
  include Speach::Dog

  # can overwrite ancestor
  def speak
    puts "Ruff"
  end
end

class Mallard
  include Speach::Duck
end

Collie.new.speak    # => "Woof"
Greyhound.new.speak # => "Ruff"
Mallard.new.speak   # => "Quack"
```

Answer (score 0):

While others answered your question about subclassing `Dog`, I would like to introduce you to a better way of naming your instances: `NameMagic`. Type `gem install y_support` in your command line, and require `NameMagic` it by:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'
```

And then:

```
class Dog
  include NameMagic
  def speak
    puts "Woof"
  end
end

Collie = Class.new Dog
Greyhound = Class.new Dog
Labrador = Class.new Dog

Chep = Collie.new
Wrex = Collie.new
Speedy = Greyhound.new
Faithful = Labrador.new
```

And then:

```
Dog.instances.each &:speak
#=> Woof
#=> Woof
#=> Woof
#=> Woof
```

`NameMagic` also allows you to query instances and their names:

```
Dog.instances
#=> [#<Collie:0xb90e3c38>, #<Collie:0xb90e1adc>, #<Greyhound:0xb90e7860>, #<Labrador:0xb90e5574>]
Collie.instances
#=> [#<Collie:0xb90e3c38>, #<Collie:0xb90e1adc>]
Labrador.instances
#=> [#<Labrador:0xb90e5574>]
Dog.instance_names
#=> [:Chep, :Wrex, :Speedy, :Faithful]
Collie.instance_names
#=> [:Chep, :Wrex]
```